# I want a arrow to point at a geolocation in react native, but I dont know how

Tags: react-native, expo, sensors

I have a "walkingapp" but its too difficult for people to walk without directions. So now I have an arrow.png that allways points up, I imported the sensors library.

```
const location = {latitude:67.37996, Longitude: 11.2348}
```

and this is how i move my arrow:

```
 <Image
            source={require("./assets/4336206.png")}
            style={[
              styles.backgroundImage,
              {
                transform: [{ rotate: `${bearing}deg` }],
                width: backgroundsize,
                height: backgroundsize,
                borderRadius: backgroundsize / 2,
                backgroundColor: "#96A35D",
              },
            ]}
          />
```

I just dont know how to work with the sensordata. I have tried using my magnetometer but then I can get north but i dont know how to get another location.